# Assembly Addressing mode

Tags: arrays, assembly, matrix, memory-address, addressing-mode

This is the code:

```
section .data
v dw 4, 6, 8, 12
len equ 4
section .text
    global main
main:
    mov eax, 0 ;this is i
    mov ebx, 0 ;this is j
cycle:
    cmp eax, 2 ;i < len/2
    jge exit
    mov ebx, 0
    jmp inner_cycle
continue:
    inc eax
    jmp cycle
inner_cycle:
    cmp ebx, 2
    jge continue
    mov di, [v + eax * 2 * 2 + ebx * 2]
    inc ebx
    jmp inner_cycle
exit:
    push dword 0
    mov eax, 0
    sub esp, 4
    int 0x80
```

I'm using an array and scanning it as a matrix, this is the C translation of the above code

```
int m[4] = {1,2,3,4};
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        printf("%d\n", m[i*2 + j]);
    }
}
```

When I try to compile the assembly code I get this error:

```
DoubleForMatrix.asm:20: error: beroset-p-592-invalid effective address
```

which refers to this line

```
mov di, [v + eax * 2 * 2 + ebx * 2]
```

can someone explain me what is wrong with this line? I think that it's because of the register dimensions, I tried with

```
mov edi, [v + eax * 2 * 2 + ebx * 2]
```

but I've got the same error.

This is assembly for Mac OS X, to make it work on another SO you have to change the exit syscall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use arbitrary expressions in assembler. Only a few addressingmodes are allowed.

basically the most complex form is  register/imm+register*scale  with scale 1,2,4,8

Of course constants (like 2*2) will probably be folded to 4, so that counts as a single scale with 4 (not as two multiplications)

Your example tries to do two multiplies  at once.

Solution: insert an extra LEA instruction to calculate v+ebx*2 and use the result in the mov.

```
     lea regx , [v+ebx*2]
     mov edi, [eax*2*2+regx]
```

where regx is a free register.

Comment: The compiler tells that `lea regx , v+ebx*2` is `invalid operand type`

Comment: It's all up to syntax. I think, you ought use LEA EAX, [V + EBX*2]

Comment: @AlekseyIvchenko since EAX is already use in the next instruction `mov edi, [eax*2*2 + regx]`, I suppose I ought use another register, correct?

Comment: @AR89 Sure. Just like mentioned above "where regx is a free register"; I used eax just to complete an example.

Answer (score 1):

The *SIB* (Scale Immediate Base) addressing mode takes only one Scale argument (1,2,4 or 8) to be applied to exactly one register.

The proposed solution is to premultiply eax by 4 (also has to modify the comparison). Then `inc eax` can be replaced with `add eax,4` and the illegal instruction by `mov di,[v+eax+ebx*2]`

A higher level optimization would be just to `for (i=0;i<4;i++) printf("%d\n",m[i]);`

Comment: Really, in many cases you don't need to make 2D scan. Use the power of assembly - work with pure 1D data.